# Searching files in dir with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I'm currently trying to search for a few files in a specific folder on Windows using `node` and `grunt`.

I have a `grunt task` that has a function to read a dir with `JSON` files, but the problem is that when I run the task, the code to read the file doesn't do anything, everything else on that `grunt task` runs perfect, but that. I'm not sure if the reference for the path is correct, but I'm also using `path.normalize()` and it does not throws any error.

This is snippet of the code:

```
..// Some other code
var fs = require('fs'),
path = require("path");

grunt.registerTask('separate', function() {
var filePath = path.normalize("C:\Users\jbernhardt\Desktop\testkeeper\jenkinsReports");

fs.readdir(filePath, function(err, filenames) {

  //This log doesn't show as it the function is not running
  grunt.log.writeln("Testing");

    if (err) {
        grunt.log.writeln("Error");
        return;
    }
    filenames.forEach(function(filename){
        grunt.log.writeln("Testing");

    });

  });
...//Some more code below for the same task
}
```

Does anyone has an idea why this snippet of the code is being skipped when I run the task? I could probably be missing some basic stuffs. Thanks!

Comment: your forward slashes are escaping your path name

Comment: Use "C:\\Users\\..." or "C:/Users/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `readdirSync` and check if your function still not working. I guess your process is finished before the callback.

Comment: Seems that you are correct, I tried that and its working!, I'll see for an alternative to read Async for best practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `__dirname` object to get the path where the current script is running:

```
..// Some other code
var fs = require('fs'),
path = require("path");

grunt.registerTask('separate', function() {

fs.readdir(__dirname, function(err, filenames) {

  //This log doesn't show as it the function is not running
  grunt.log.writeln("Testing");

    if (err) {
        grunt.log.writeln("Error");
        return;
    }
    filenames.forEach(function(filename){
        grunt.log.writeln("Testing");

    });

  });
...//Some more code below for the same task
}
```

You can find more info [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname).

Answer (score 0):

you need change your path

```
var filePath = path.normalize("C:\\Users\\jbernhardt\\Desktop\\testkeeper\\jenkinsReports");
```

Also To achieve consistent results when working with Windows file paths on any operating system, use path.win32:

```
path.win32.basename('C:\\Users\\jbernhardt\\Desktop\\testkeeper\\jenkinsReports"');
```

You can read about https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_windows_vs_posix

Answer (score 0):

The slash in path are being escaped.

```
"C:\\Users\\jbernhardt\\Desktop\\testkeeper\\jenkinsReports"
```

should solve your issue.